# Does the text "this damage cannot be reduced or prevented in any way" affect healing that damage?

Tags: dnd-4e, healing

There are several effects and items that deal damage to the user and have the language "This damage cannot be reduced or prevented in any way". For example the *Bloodclaw Weapon* in Adventurer's Vault.

I know that means that damage reduction wouldn't apply. And that you couldn't let another party member (such as a paladin) step in and take that damage for you.

Does that text affect the healing of that damage in any way?

Is there any reason I couldn't regenerate or second wind to recover those hit points?

Comment: Why do you think this clause prevents damage transferal?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No this does not stop you healing the damage.

The damage can not be reduced or prevented, you have to take the damage.

What happens after that, eg healing, has nothing to do with the damage once you've actually taken it. So you aren't reducing or preventing the amount of damage you *take*.

Comment: Worth noting, is that use of regeneration powers or your Second Wind depends upon your surviving the damage taken and remaining conscious.

Answer (score 4):

As to my knowledge, this phrase does not affect recovering from the damage once it was received.